# Spring batch meta data tables are not getting created in the schema I configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am configuring a JpaTransactionManager with existing datasource and LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for my batch job. When I debug, the JpaTransactionManager is set with schema "dbs" where I want metadata tables should go. But in reality, the metadata tables are created in 'public' schema. database I am using is 'postgress'

I tried extending DefaultBatchConfigurer and and all possible ways, still the result is same

Here is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL:jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres}
    username: ${DB_USER_NAME:postgres}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:******}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: false
        generate_statistics: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        default_schema: dbs
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: false
    initializer:
      enabled: true
```

And the Batch Config file looks like:

```
public class StatusBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Primary
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        String schema = (String) entityManagerFactory.getObject().getProperties().get("hibernate.default_schema");
        System.out.println(schema); //prints 'dbs'
        return transactionManager;
    }



    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        try {
            launcher.setJobRepository(createJobRepository());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return launcher;
    }

}
```

What else to configure here to save metadata tables in 'dbs' schema

Comment: Have you tried to set the `spring.batch.initialize-schema` property? Spring Batch works with a `DataSource`, it does not know about schemas. So you need to configure a datasource with the target schema and tell spring batch to use it. BTW, you might want to override the `DefaultBatchConfigurer#setDataSource` and pass the datasource you want to store batch meta-data.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, yeah, If I append DB url with '?currentSchema=dbs', it is working. But the problem here is, the DB url, username and password are dynamic. We have a backend script that generates postgress url, username and password and the scripts are not maintained by us.

Comment: That's another problem, and Spring (Batch) can do nothing for it.

Comment: yep, I agree @MahmoudBenHassine. Thanks for letting me know how spring batch looks at datasource